# How to rightly decode data in block-listener.go example?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm using block-listener to listen transactions in one channel to send notification in another. But i haven't clue how to decode data that print [block-listener.go](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/examples/events/block-listener/block-listener.go) example.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what do you mean by decoding the data is the following block of the `[block-lister.go][1]` takes care to print transactions for you:

```
for {
    select {
    case b := <-a.notfy:
        fmt.Println("")
        fmt.Println("")
        fmt.Println("Received block")
        fmt.Println("--------------")
        txsFltr := util.TxValidationFlags(b.Block.Metadata.Metadata[common.BlockMetadataIndex_TRANSACTIONS_FILTER])
        for i, r := range b.Block.Data.Data {
            tx, _ := getTxPayload(r)
            if tx != nil {
                chdr, err := utils.UnmarshalChannelHeader(tx.Header.ChannelHeader)
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Print("Error extracting channel header\n")
                    return
                }
                if txsFltr.IsInvalid(i) {
                    fmt.Println("")
                    fmt.Println("")
                    fmt.Printf("Received invalid transaction from channel '%s'\n", chdr.ChannelId)
                    fmt.Println("--------------")
                    fmt.Printf("Transaction invalid: TxID: %s\n", chdr.TxId)
                } else {
                    fmt.Printf("Received transaction from channel '%s': \n\t[%v]\n", chdr.ChannelId, tx)
                    if event, err := getChainCodeEvents(r); err == nil {
                        if len(chaincodeID) != 0 && event.ChaincodeId == chaincodeID {
                            fmt.Println("")
                            fmt.Println("")
                            fmt.Printf("Received chaincode event from channel '%s'\n", chdr.ChannelId)
                            fmt.Println("------------------------")
                            fmt.Printf("Chaincode Event:%+v\n", event)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if you would like you can also use following function to get block printed in JSON format:

```
protolator.DeepMarshalJSON(os.Stdout, t.Block)
```